# Django does not display images

Tags: django, image, web-applications

I am trying to create a site with Django, however, I cannot get images to be displayed.

My model is:

```
class Place(models.Model):
Pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="media",blank=True,null=True)
StoreName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
Address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
OpenDate=models.DateField('date opened')
SubmitDate=models.DateTimeField('date submitted')
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.StoreName
```

and the view is:

```
def PlaceView(request,thisPlace):
PlaceObject=Place.objects.get(StoreName=thisPlace)
return render_to_response('Pages/place.html',{'PlaceObj':PlaceObject})
```

then in "place.html"

```
<img src="{{PlaceObj.Pic.url}}" alt="test" width="50px" height="50px"
```

But the picture is never diplayed. In the console I get a 404 error:

```
[02/Aug/2012 14:49:50] "GET /Media/media/24228302_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2220
```

I have set the MEDIA_ROOT to a folder (/home/Project_root/Media/) in my system and the MEDIA_URL ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/Media/'

Is there something I am not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a URL pattern in `urls.py` (or wherever your URL patterns are located) for serving media images. Like this:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
```

Make sure to include `from django.conf import settings` in your urls.py file.